# How do you efficiently determine if a Postgres table has rows

Tags: postgresql

I did this tests and the results seems the count function scale linearly. I have another function relying strongly in the efficiency to know if there are any data, so I would like to know how to replace this select count(*) with another more efficient (maybe constant?) query or data structure.

> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f truncate_and_insert_1000_rows.sql > NUL
>
> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f count_data.sql

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Aggregate  (cost=36.75..36.76 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.762..0.763 rows=1
loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on datos  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=0) (actual time=0.02
8..0.468 rows=1000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: **0.846 ms**
(3 filas)

> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f truncate_and_insert_10000_rows.sql > NUL
>
> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f count_data.sql

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Aggregate  (cost=197.84..197.85 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=6.191..6.191 rows=
1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on datos  (cost=0.00..173.07 rows=9907 width=0) (actual time=0.0
09..3.407 rows=10000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: **6.271 ms**
(3 filas)

> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f truncate_and_insert_100000_rows.sql > NUL
>
> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f count_data.sql

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Aggregate  (cost=2051.60..2051.61 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=74.075..74.076 r
ows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on datos  (cost=0.00..1788.48 rows=105248 width=0) (actual time=
0.032..46.024 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: **74.164 ms**
(3 filas)

> psql -d prueba -U postgres -f truncate_and_insert_1000000_rows.sql > NUL
>
> psql -d testdb -U postgres -f count_data.sql

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Aggregate  (cost=19720.00..19720.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=637.486..637.4
87 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on datos  (cost=0.00..17246.60 rows=989360 width=0) (actual time
=0.028..358.831 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: **637.582 ms**
(3 filas)

the definition of data is

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  text VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk3 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Also I'd tried limiting the result set: EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(*) from data LIMIT 1; but the response times are pretty similar...

Comment: That's because you need to test SELECT * FROM <table> LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) useful.

Answer (score 17):

select true from table limit 1;

Answer (score 7):

```
select exists(select * from your_table_here) as has_row
```

Comment: Exists returns true if the inner query returns any rows.  It doesn't actually examine the content of the rows, so the `*` doesn't imply field retrieval.

Comment: Donnie: indeed. in fact, even if you put 1/0 inside SELECT FROM your_table_here, it will not divide-by-zero error

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.primary_key IS NOT NULL FROM table t LIMIT 1;
```

You will get TRUE if there are records and NULL if there are none.

Comment: -1 Not the most optimal solution because you're examining a column from the table, which in the event of your examined column not having a NOT NULL constraint, may be inaccurate. It would be much better to `SELECT 1 FROM table LIMIT 1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is 1 row or no rows. Limit your query to the first row - why count all of the rows just to find out if there's 1 or more, or zero...

use the equivalent of  ROWNUM = 1 or TOP 1 or whatever postgres gives you.

Comment: Thanks, I hate it when people offer solutions for other platforms but I knew the concept surely had to be pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

How a count on the primary key field where it is NOT NULL, limiting the query at 1 response?

Since a primary key *must* exist, if there is one, you have data, yes?